# Force Retry Getting Certificate in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a node js application and have been getting the following error after an update:

```
events.js:85  
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event  
            ^  
Error: certificate not trusted  
    at Error (native)  
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:929:36)  
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:104:17)  
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:460:8)
```

I was wondering if there was a way with node to retry getting the SSL certificate that has since been updated and should work. I think my server's cache is using an old url or something, thus grabbing the invalid cert. Or is it an issue where I need to wait 24~ hours for the internet to settle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue "getting the certificate" -- this error tells you that the certificate presented by the remote server (something that happens at the beginning of every SSL connection) is:

- not signed by a trusted Certificate Authority
- missing a required intermediate certificate
- expired

In this situation, retrying would certainly result in the exact same error.

Remember that node does not use your operating system's root CA store; it comes [bundled with its own trust store](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h).  If the server's certificate is not signed by one of these CAs or if you are on an evil network that MITMs SSL connections, then your connection will fail.

If this is a https connection, I'd start by using a browser to inspect the certificate presented by the remote server.

Comment: I see.

I am working with the discordapp api and yesterday during their downtime they had changed their certificate (the bad one) and then this morning they put their old one (which was working) back up.